# Adding XUTILS, XLRD in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Good Day! Is there a way to add the Python Library Package xutils,xlrd in odoo?
right now the only library can be used is xlwt I Just want to create a Template Excel file and just append it after the copy of the excel file. and I just working xlwt for all the work in excel and right now I'm Just using a windows server for this.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day! My Answer to this problem is just copy the Directory Library Package from the Python Directories and Just paste it in Odoo\server\ Directory

Hope this will help